# What does the rust-analyzer error "could not resolve macro `$crate::format_args`" mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

I'm using rust-analyzer version 0.2.408 on Visual Studio Code.

I'm writing a command line application that involves centering text in the terminal. This is the function I wrote to do this:

```rs
use console::{Alignment, pad_str};

fn get_padded_row(row: &str, width: u16, symbol: Option<char>) -> String {
    let symbol = symbol.unwrap_or(' ');
    return pad_str(row, width as usize, Alignment::Center, None)
        .to_string()
        .replace(' ', &symbol.to_string());
}
```

This function works perfectly fine, and there were no errors with it. Then I wrote a test:

```rs
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use crate::get_padded_row;

    #[test]
    fn row_padding_dashes() {
        let padded_row = get_padded_row("hello", 15, Some('-'));
        assert_eq!(
            padded_row, "-----hello-----".to_string(),
            "`get_padded_row` was not correct, got `{}`", padded_row
        );
    }
}
```

The code still works perfectly fine. Both `cargo run` and `cargo test` work, the function passes the test, and `cargo check` returns no issues. But rust-analyzer gives an error, highlighting everything from the `tr};` in the `use` statement to the `p` right after `return`: "could not resolve macro `$crate::format_args` rust-analyzer(macro-error)". Searching for this error returns nothing. VSCode links me to [rust-analyzer user manual](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#macro-error), which says only "This diagnostic is shown for macro expansion errors". Restarting VSCode and reinstalling rust-analyzer have done nothing. The error always comes back, and highlighting the same oddly specific region. The only way I've found to get rid of it while keeping rust-analyzer installed is to remove the test.

Judging from how the error is about macro expansion, and how removing the test fixes the issue, I'd imagine it's caused by the `#[test]` macro, but it's strange that rustc finds no issues at all with my code while rust-analyzer is freaking out about this error. So far, I've had better experiences with rust-analyzer than with the official Rust VSCode extension, but I'm on the verge of switching back to fix this issue.

Comment: [This is a bug in rust-analyzer (#6716)](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/issues/6716)

Comment: ~5h lost ;/ on that ;////////////////

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a [bug in rust-analyzer](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/issues/6716). For now, you can disable the warning in your `settings.json`:

```json
"rust-analyzer.diagnostics.disabled": [
  "macro-error"
]
```

The bug was fixed on nightly, so you could install the [nightly binary of rust-analyzer](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/releases/tag/nightly) from GitHub, or you could just wait a couple days for the fix to land on stable.

Alternatively, you could downgrade to rls version `0.2.400`, because the bug was caused by a commit in version `0.2.408`:

```
Extensions Icon -> rust-analyzer -> Manage (gear icon) -> Install Another Version
```

Comment: installing nightly rust analyzer fixed the issue, but you need to have procMacro to `True` in your settings for rust analyzer

Answer (score 5):

Three months later and there seems to be a [bug with Nightly release](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/issues/6038#issuecomment-798888016)? Unsure.

I added `unresolved-macro-call` to Diagnostics: Disabled settings for rust-analyzer.

Answer (score 4):

I've tried many things, read the open issue on github, etc which is tagged as solved, but persists here.

For vscode users, open settings (json) and disable by adding:

```json
    "rust-analyzer.procMacro.enable": false
```